# is there a way to externalise the value of @Scheduled annotation in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

As @Scheduled annotation key 'fixedRate' in spring boot will only accept constant, i want to know is there any other way to externalise this property to the external properties file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#annotation.type.field.summary); Most of the properties have a `String` suffixed counterpart as well, in your case `fixedRateString`. The String-suffixed properties can be used to insert SPeL and placeholder expressions, for instance:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRateString="${scheduled.fixedRate}")
public void someMethod() { ... }
```

application.properties:

```
scheduled.fixedRate=1000
```